# abnormal behavior of scanf

Tags: c, scanf

I have code as below which scans a matrix, w - width of matrix, h - heigth of matrix.

I am using Visual Studio 2010.

Every time I get a char it increases j by 2 (I put the break point and come to know this behavior).

```
int w = 0, h = 0;
char map[21][21];
int i,j;

scanf("%d%d", &w, &h);
for(i = 1; i <= h; ++i){
    for(j = 1; j <= w; ++j){
        //fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%c",&map[i][j]);
        //fflush(stdin);
    }
}
```

What can be the reason behind this?

at the time of scan i am giving value, w = 7, h = 5.

I don't see any error in my code....Please help me.

Comment: `fflush(stdin)` has undefined behavior, don't use it !

Comment: what input are you using? If I give it something like `7 5abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHI` (which is what it appears to expect) it works as expected.  Perhaps you are trying to read data in some different format?

Comment: thanks for fflush(stdin) behavior, I didn't know it. But still facing the issue.

Comment: @ChrisDodd...No no my format is correct. I am giving input one by one.

Comment: @P0W: If you run on POSIX-derived systems, `fflush(stdin)` has undefined behaviour.  If you run on Windows-derived systems, the behaviour is documented by Microsoft; it discards any data already in the input buffer.

Comment: Array indices start at `0`, in C.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths; I think I am overflow now. :(

Answer (score 5):

The problem is due to `'\n'` characters (on pressing   <kbd>Enter</kbd> )  left behind by `scanf`.
One way to eat up these newline character is place a `' '` before `%c` in `scanf`;

```
 scanf(" %c",&map[i][j]);  
        ^
        |
      space
```

Another way is to use a loop to eat up all the `\n` by `getchar()`

```
  int ch;
  while((ch=getchar())!='\n' && ch != EOF );
```

Comment: It will work if the user presses enter several times; the blank in the format eats up all the spaces, tabs, newlines before the next non-blank character is read by `%c`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler; Yes you are right. I thought about reading by `getchar`. That's why I mistaken. Edited now.

Answer (score 2):

You need to skip trailing newline from previous `scanf`

Don't use `fflush(stdin)`

Use:

```
int c;

while((c=getchar())!='\n' && c != EOF ); //eats newline came from scanf
```

after `scanf` call

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer to **vuppala srikar**.
His question "[fscanf issue while reading input from text file [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46451225/fscanf-issue-while-reading-input-from-text-file)" does not appear to me to be an exact duplicate :

In his question, the `scanf` is done on an opened text file (`fptr`).

Instead of :

```
while((fscanf(fptr,"%c %d",&c,&val))==2)
{
    printf("%c %d\n",c,val);
}
```

which reads only the first line of the file, I suggest :

```
char line [50] ;
while (fgets( line,sizeof( line ),fptr ))
    if (sscanf(line,"%c %d",&c,&val)==2)
        {
        printf("%c %d\n",c,val);
        }
```

I hope my answer arrives not too late...