# fscanf issue while reading input from text file

Tags: c, printf, scanf

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
FILE *fptr;
int val;
char filename[100], c;
printf("Enter the filename to open \n");
scanf("%s", filename);
fptr = fopen(filename, "r");
if (fptr == NULL){
    printf("error\n");
    exit(0);
}

while((fscanf(fptr,"%c %d",&c,&val))==2)
{
    printf("%c %d\n",c,val);
}
fclose(fptr);
return 0;
}
```

I am trying to scan values from a text file using fscanf but i am able to read only one value even though i kept a loop.
sample input:

```
d 7
i 10
i 5
i 10
d 10
```

my output is:

```
d 7
```

Comment: `"%c %d"` --> `" %c %d"`, add space.

Comment: there is a space

Comment: Add space before `%c`.

Comment: Kudos for testing the return value of `fscanf()` in `fscanf(fptr,"%c %d",&c,&val))==2`.  Certainly helps narrow the problem quickly.

Comment: the answer for the solution is to place a \n after reading %c %d 
i.e., fscanf(fptr,"%c %d\n",&c,&val)==2